# Concurrent inserts in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concurrency

I'm having trouble with understanding how concurrent inserts works in given scenario: we have 2 separate procedures (p1, p2). Both procedures insert data into same table.

If the p1 runs with let's say 30k inserts it will succeed in approx 1h - 1h30min.
The p1 procedure uses `insert all into` and inside we have 2 inserts (one of which is on the said table). Table also have a insert trigger (400 lines of code with different checking).

Howewer if p2 tries to make even one insert, the p2 insert will succeed instantly but p1 insert will finish after 5h or so. P2 uses the same table but first it will select rowtype then it will insert int to the table.

Thus the question: if it happens because database make kind of snapshot because there is heavy operation being processed and another make select and insert at the same time?

**EDIT:** don't know if this may be important but table has 21 indices.

Also worth noticing that problematic_table has modification date. Modification date on all 30k or 60k is the same. So I believe SYSDATE is stored in memory inside insert all into call.

This another insert from P2 happens let's say 0.5h after insert all and always is committed right after it's called. Also what's important that P2 make insert using selected row from problematic_table. It stores it as ROWTYPE.

```
insert all into problematic_table (column1, columnN, column37)
values (sequence.nextval,
        sequence.currval,
        some_data_hard_typed,
        SOME_DATA_COLUMNS_FROM_LAST_SELECT)
into another_table (c1, columnN, c32)
values (v1,
        valueN,
        some_data_hard_typed,
        SOME_DATA_COLUMNS_FROM_LAST_SELECT)
        (select c1, c2..c29 from temp_table_used to insert)
```

Comment: The procedures are being called from different sessions, and whichever does the insert first is blocking the other. If `p2` executes first, it sounds like no commit is being issued for 3.5-4 hours - after which the blocked `p1` inserts can be processed, and the rest of the procedure can complete. So - is there a reason for the delayed commit? Is the `p2` session doing useful work for the rest of that time (and needs to all be in the same transaction), or was the commit just missed?

Comment: If "P2" inserted into a unique key value and did not commit and, later, "P1" tries to insert the same unique value, "P1" will wait forever until "P2" commits or rolls back.  Other than that, the answer to your question is generally "no" -- a single row insert in "P2", committed immediately, would not be responsible for "P1"'s run time degrading from 1.5 hours to 5.0 hours.  You should post more details if you want guidance on what the problem might be.  I would look at the `SELECT` statement driving the `INSERT ALL` in "P1".

Comment: Oracle should implement a CONSISTENT read.  All changes are collected and only made visible to everyone else after a COMMIT.  if you do a whole bunch prior to commit, then there is overhead to maintain the read consistency for everyone while it is in process.